# What is the bias variance profile of sample mean estimated from bootstrapped samples?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling

It is not obvious to me why the idea of sampling with replacement is an improvement over random samples. Does sample mean from bootstrapped samples generate unbiased or consistent estimators? How does $$var[\bar{x}]$$ from bootstrapped samples compare with that from random samples?